# Unity (C#) - public variable won't work in one specific function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I have a variable called info which is of my own class called Kingdom Perk. It holds info about each different upgrade you can add to your kingdom and it gets passed to a script through a setup function, and in that function the public variable "info" gets assigned to whats passed in.

In an update function, if I write:

```
Debug.Log("Perk Name: " + info.Name);
```

It tells me "Cannon" or "Walls" e.t.c

But if I try to access it in a function that is run when a button is pressed, it tells me that "info" is null.

The setup function is always run before the button pressed function, and the same global variable works in the update function as it always tells me the correct thing, its only broken in this function.

Any help appreciated, ask if you need more detail

Thanks

EDIT: A different global variable also shows as null in this function only.

EDIT 2:

```
private KingdomPerk info;

public void Setup(KingdomPerk data)
{
    info = data;
    perkName.text = data.Name;
    perkType.text = "Type: " + data.Type.ToString();
    perkHealth.text = "Health: " + data.Health.ToString() + "HP";
    perkUpgradeCost.text = "Upgrade Cost: " + data.UpgradeCost.ToString();
    perkImage.sprite = data.Sprite;
}

public void UpgradeButtonPressed()
{
    float money = FindObjectOfType<MapGenerator>().worldInfo.money;

    if (money >= info.UpgradeCost && info.Level != info.MaxUpgradeLevel)
    {
        Debug.Log("We've got enough!");
        money -= info.UpgradeCost;
        info.DamagePerShot *= info.DamageMultiplier;
        info.Health *= info.HealthMultiplier;
        info.Level++;
        info.UpgradeCost *= info.CostMultiplier;
        info.FireRate *= info.FireRateMultiplier;
        RefreshInfo();
    }
    else if (money < info.UpgradeCost)
        Debug.Log("Get more money!");
    else if (info.Level == info.MaxUpgradeLevel)
        Debug.Log("Already max level!");
}
```

Setup is called here, in a different script:

```
void RefreshListItems()
{
    ClearListItems();

    for (var i = 0; i < perks.Count; i++)
    {
        if (perks[i].UnlockLevel <= FindObjectOfType<MapGenerator>().worldInfo.playerLevel)
        {
            GameObject perkObject = Instantiate(itemPrefab);
            perkObject.transform.SetParent(scrollViewTransform);
            PerkListItem perkItem = perkObject.GetComponent<PerkListItem>();
            perkItem.Setup(perks[i]);
            upgradeGOList.Add(perkObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? Ie. Where `info` is initialized, where it's used, where it's declared? There's not enough context here to currently identify the root cause.

Comment: Ok updated it, if there's anything else let me know

Comment: You have to call your `Setup(KingdomPerk data)` function and pass in new instance of `KingdomPerk` in order to initialize `info`.

Comment: Then how come "info" works in every other function apart from this one?

Comment: Sorry but `info` is not even a public variable like your title and body of questions say. It is a private variable. You are likely accessing another variable and thinking it is this variable.

Comment: It doesnt work as public either. I only access it within the script in which it was defined.

Comment: You're likely accessing a different instance of the object than you think. Ensure your button is properly wired up to the right MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - The onclick event was referencing the script on the prefab rather than the instantiated copies of that.